# \usepackage{emptypage} for odd pages

Tags: emptypage

I want to ask, is it possible that if I want to use the `\usepackage{emptypage}` but to make sure that every chapter starts at the odd pages? If yes, what should I add within my preamble/document? Since as I know that the package is formated to start the new chapters at the even pages. Thank you.

Comment: I can't reproduce "the package is formated to start the new chapters at the even pages" If I create a small example document, such as the following, all chapters start at odd pages: ``\documentclass[twoside]{book}
\usepackage{emptypage}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\chapter{chapter}
\lipsum

\chapter{chapter}
\lipsum \lipsum

\chapter{chapter}
\lipsum
\end{document}`. If you get a different output in your document, please prepare a small and compilable [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) allowing others to reproduce the output you get.

Comment: I see that the difference between my work and yours is the `twoside`. I am currently using the template provided by my institute which using `oneside` instead. However, there seems to be a lacking with the first page at the odd page for every chapter and we need to manually add a dummy page for any chapter that starts at an even page. Also, when I used `twoside` instead of `oneside`, the left margin and right margin will be different for odd and even pages. I want to avoid that from happening which will lead to extra works for another formatting that needs to be changed later on.

Answer (score 1):

We have no idea about the template (class? package?) provided by your institute. Do you have to use it?

In the `book` class by default chapters start on recto (odd-numbered) pages while in the `report` class they start on the next page. These can be altered by using class options `openright` (default for `book`) or `openany` (default for `report`). Perhaps you could use the `openright` option if your template allows it.

Based on @leandriis comment here is a `book` class MWE that meets your requirements for keeping constant placement of the text block.

```
% emptypageprob.tex  SE 590216
\documentclass[twoside]{book}
\usepackage{emptypage}
\usepackage{lipsum}

% make the margins equal (could use the geometry package instead)
\addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{\evensidemargin}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0.5\oddsidemargin}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{\oddsidemargin}

\begin{document}
\chapter{First}
\lipsum
\chapter{Second}
\lipsum[1]
\chapter{Third}
\lipsum[1]
\chapter{Fourth}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```